# Kafka CommitFailedException when running 2 consumers separately with different topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to run 2 consumers subscribed to 2 different topics. Both the consumer programs run properly when running one at a time, but when running them at the same time, one consumer always displays the exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

I followed the suggestions and have set the `max.pool.size` to 2, and `session.timeout.ms` to 30000, `heartbeat.interval.ms` to 1000

Below is my consumer function, this function is same for both the files, only the topic name changes to `Test2`, and I am running these two functions in 2 different classes running both at the same time.

```
    public void consume()
    {
        //Kafka consumer configuration settings
        List<String> topicNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        topicNames.add("Test1");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "2");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"); 
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(topicNames);
        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.println("Record: "+record.value());
                String responseString = "successfull";
                if (responseString.equals("successfull")) {
                    consumer.commitSync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception: ", e);
        }
        finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
```

Due to this error, the records are not getting committed in the `Kafka` topic. 
How do I overcome this error?

Comment: How are you running Kafka? Is it possible when you start/restart it (ie the broker), that it still contains management info from a previous session?

Comment: Try different group ids for each consumer

Comment: I am running kafka server and broker separately on the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to assign different group IDs to consumer. You are making two consumer with same group ID (that is okay), **but calling subscribe twice is not okay**.

You are able to run one consumer at a time because you are calling subscribe only once.

If you need any further help let me know. Happy to help.